# Declaring Integer Outside of Method?

Tags: java, variables, integer, declaration

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputTest {
static void monster() {
    System.out.println("You ran into a monster!");
    System.out.println("He did 10 damage!");
    health -= 10;
    System.out.println("You have " + health + " health left!");
}
static void potion() {
    System.out.println("You ran into a potion!");
    System.out.println("It healed 10 damage!");
    health += 10;
    System.out.println("You have " + health + " health left!");
}
static void bag() {
    System.out.println("You ran into a bag!");
    System.out.println("It did... Nothing!");
}
static void random() {
    double random = Math.random();
    if(random >= 0 && random <= 0.33) {
        monster();
    } else if(random >= 0.24 && random <= 0.66) {
        potion();
    } else {
        bag();
    }
}
static void turn() {
    System.out.println("Do you want to go left or right?");
    Scanner turn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String leftOrRight = turn.nextLine();
    if(leftOrRight.equals("Right")) {
        System.out.println("You turned right and...");
        random();
    } else if(leftOrRight.equals("Left")){
        System.out.println("You turned left and...");
        random();
    } else {
        System.out.println("You entered an invalid answer...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int health = 50;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        turn();
    }
    System.out.println("You won!");
    }
}
```

This is the non-working code.
The monster(); and health(); methods are the ones I have trouble with.
It outputs that I have not declared 'health.'
I see why it says this, is there any way to fix this.
It just won't let me use the health integer inside the method.
It is supposed to take health and subtract 10, as you see.

Comment: Make `health` a global variable. So above your monster method, do `public int health = 50;`. You can have the methods use the health defined in main. Then create a getter/setter for `health`

Comment: @Ascalonian No. Make `health` a static class parameter. `static int health = 50;`

Comment: @MikeCAT - why make it static?

Comment: @Ascalonian Because it is used from static functions without creating an instance.

Comment: Hi Derek, welcome to SO. Please try posting a [MCVE] in the future. This makes it easier for others to answer your questions.

Answer (score -1):

Make health a class level static variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputTest {
     private static int health = 50;

     /*rest of the methods as they are*/

}
```

Comment: `static variable` - so just do it

Comment: Thank you all so much, it works now, with a few tweaks. (:

Comment: @ScaryWombat why do we need static here ??

Comment: because calling it from a static method.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    private static int health = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            turn();
        }
        System.out.println("You won!");
    }

    static void monster() {
        System.out.println("You ran into a monster!");
        System.out.println("He did 10 damage!");
        health -= 10;
        System.out.println("You have " + health + " health left!");
    }

    static void potion() {
        System.out.println("You ran into a potion!");
        System.out.println("It healed 10 damage!");
        health += 10;
        System.out.println("You have " + health + " health left!");
    }

    static void bag() {
        System.out.println("You ran into a bag!");
        System.out.println("It did... Nothing!");
    }

    static void random() {
        double random = Math.random();
        if (random >= 0 && random <= 0.33) {
            monster();
        } else if (random >= 0.24 && random <= 0.66) {
            potion();
        } else {
            bag();
        }
    }

    static void turn() {
        System.out.println("Do you want to go left or right?");
        Scanner turn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String leftOrRight = turn.nextLine();
        // turn.close();
        if (leftOrRight.equals("Right")) {
            System.out.println("You turned right and...");
            random();
        } else if (leftOrRight.equals("Left")) {
            System.out.println("You turned left and...");
            random();
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid answer...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See below the modified code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputTest {
    private static int health = 50;
    static void monster() {
        System.out.println("You ran into a monster!");
        System.out.println("He did 10 damage!");
        health -= 10;
        System.out.println("You have " + health + " health left!");
    }

    static void potion() {
        System.out.println("You ran into a potion!");
        System.out.println("It healed 10 damage!");
        health += 10;
        System.out.println("You have " + health + " health left!");
    }

    static void bag() {
        System.out.println("You ran into a bag!");
        System.out.println("It did... Nothing!");
    }

    static void random() {
        double random = Math.random();
        if (random >= 0 && random <= 0.33) {
            monster();
        } else if (random >= 0.24 && random <= 0.66) {
            potion();
        } else {
            bag();
        }
    }

    static void turn() {
        System.out.println("Do you want to go left or right?");
        Scanner turn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String leftOrRight = turn.nextLine();
        if (leftOrRight.equals("Right")) {
            System.out.println("You turned right and...");
            random();
        } else if (leftOrRight.equals("Left")) {
            System.out.println("You turned left and...");
            random();
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid answer...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            turn();
        }
        System.out.println("You won!");
    }
}
```

Regards